# TypeError: User is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

I am trying to save a user to mongodb database using post request as follow, but I got the error `TypeError: User is not a function.` It's a pretty simple set up of the code but i can't figure out anything wrong with it.

I am using: 
mongoose 4.8.6 
express 4.15.2 
node 6.6

```
// models/user.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        lowercase: true
    },
    password: String
});

// server.js
var User = require('./models/user');

app.post('/create-user', function(req, res, next) {
    var user = new User(); // TypeError: User is not a constructor
    user.email = req.body.email;
    user.password = req.body.password;

    user.save(function(err) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.json('Successfully register a new user');
    });
});
```

[image]

Comment: It would be better if you've shared User module as the problem is related to that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to create `model` from your `UserSchema` and then export it, then you can create new User objects.

```
// models/user.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        lowercase: true
    },
    password: String
});

module.exports =  mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
```

Comment: Hello Nenad, 
Even I'm doing what suggested. But still I'm getting same kind of error.

Comment: My environment: MacOS
mongoose 4.11.0
express 4.15.3
node 9.5.0

Comment: My model file: user.model.js

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(

{

userid: String,
 name:
 {
   type: String,
   required: true
 },
});

const user = module.exports = mongoose.model('user', userSchema );

//This also giving the same issue.

//module.exports = mongoose.model('user', userSchema );

Answer (score 5):

You got that error because you exported the modules wrongly,
In my case in the models/user I had written `module.export` leaving out the `s` at the end
When you run the code it then gives you that error
I would advice checking on your `module.exports =  mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)` spellings

Answer (score 1):

```
// models/user.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        lowercase: true
},
    password: String
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
module.exports =  { User } <-- capital 'U'
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the lowercase `user` variable into uppercase (like below) strangely worked:

`const User = mongoose.model('users');`

I really thought this was just a best practice but eventually, seems to be mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same error but this worked for me.

I did change my export file

```
var User = mongoose.model('User',userSchema);
module.exports = {User};
```

To

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this `var user = new User();` for this `var User = new User();`

Answer (score 0):

I also got struck in the same issue but I had no mistake in exporting file and remaining all codes were fine as well.

The only problem with my code was I had imported the model as below:

```
const { User } = require('./Database/Models/UserModel');
```

Since I had **only one model exported** from the file UserModel.js, I should not use **{}** while importing the model.

Correct way of importing would be:

```
const User = require('./Database/Models/UserModel');
```

And my issue got resolved.