# '"<variable>" is not a constructor' and Cannot read property 'find' of undefined errors with mongoose

Tags: angular, mongoose

After going through all the threads similar to the error messages in the title and after trying all the steps in those solutions provided and unsuccessfully I am posting the problem again.

I re-wrote the code as solved in the threads and corrected all case sensitive issues.

1. "[Mongoose TypeError: User is not a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774997/mongoose-typeerror-user-is-not-a-constructor)"
2. "[TypeError: User is not a constructor - Mongoose Node.js Express-Validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49275169/typeerror-user-is-not-a-constructor-mongoose-node-js-express-validator)"
3. "[TypeError: User is not a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42747721/typeerror-user-is-not-a-constructor)"

Still, I get the same error. Help me, please. What is the meaning of the error in the first half of the title?

**userModel.js**

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var User = mongoose.model('User',{
    username:{
        type: String
    },
    password:{
        type: String
    }
});


module.exports= User ;
```

**userRoute.js**

```
const express=require('express');
const userRouter=express.Router();
var app=express();

var {User}  = require('../models/userModel');

userRouter.route('/').post(function(req,res)
{
    var newUser = new User({ // 'User is not a constructor'
        username:req.body.name,
        password:req.body.name
    });
    newUser.save((err,doc) => {
            if(!err)
            res.send(docs);
        });
});


userRouter.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    User.find((err,docs) => { ' TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of 
                               // undefined'
        if(!err) {res.send(docs);}
        else{
            console.log("Problem retreiving documents",JSON.stringify(err,undefined,2));
        }
    });
});

module.exports=userRouter;
```

Comment: try changing the import as `var User  = require('../models/userModel');`

Comment: I tried that as well. It is not working. I know I made an ugly mistake but could not find out what is that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like **User Schema** is not initialized. Try changing code as below for **userModel.js**

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    username:{
        type: String
    },
    password:{
        type: String
    }
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);


module.exports= User ;
```